# How to deploy neoload in docker

Tags: neoload

Please does anyone know how to deploy neoload on Docker. I have looked at the neoload package on docker hub but it doesn't seem to make much sense. I want to use it for performance testing. the link is https://hub.docker.com/r/neotys/neoload-controller/

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i followed what was on the url as I showed you but it doesn't work. its not really straightforward. Can you help if you know how to do it thanks

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the documentation, there are 2 ways to deploy your neoload controller on docker:

- **Managed:** this mode only works with a neoload web.
- **Standalone:** basically when you run your neoload container, you give it some parameters like the neoload project, the number of virtual users etc... The test is launched at the start of the container.
  From the [docker hub documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/neotys/neoload-controller/):

```
docker run -d --rm \
-e PROJECT_NAME={project-name} \
-e SCENARIO={scenario} \
-e NTS_URL={nts-url} \
-e NTS_LOGIN={login:password} \
-e COLLAB_URL={collab-url} \
-e LICENSE_ID={license-id} \
-e VU_MAX={vu-max} \
-e DURATION_MAX={duration-max} \
-e NEOLOADWEB_URL={nlweb-onpremise-apiurl:port} \
-e NEOLOADWEB_TOKEN={nlweb-token} \
-e PUBLISH_RESULT={publish-result} \
neotys/neoload-controller
```

You either have to pull the license from a Neoload Web or a NTS server.
I will need more informations about your problem to help you.

Regards